# How to integrate $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2-b}}$

Tags: integration

So my problem is to integrate

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2-b}},$$

where $a,b$ are positive constants. What rule should I use here? Should substitution be used or trigonometric integrals?

The [solution](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%281%29%2F%28sqrt%28ax%5E2-b%29%29) should be:

$$\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{ax^2-b}+ax\right)}{\sqrt{a}}+C$$

Thank you for any help =)

Comment: By the way, if you want, write **\mathrm dx** to generate $\mathrm dx$ as opposed to $dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question says "Should substitution be used or trigonometric integrals?".  But a trigonometric substitution is a substitution, not an alternative to substitution.
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2-b}} = \int\frac{dx/\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{\frac a b x^2 - 1}} = \int \frac{\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta/\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{\sec^2\theta - 1}}
$$
Then use the fact that $\sec^2\theta-1=\tan^2\theta$.  The substitution is $\sec\theta=x\sqrt{\frac a b}$ so that $\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta=dx\sqrt{\frac a b}$ and thus $\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta/\sqrt{a} = dx/\sqrt{b}$.

$$
\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
& \text{When  you have} & \text{then use} & \text{so that} \\
\hline
& (\text{variable})^2 + \text{positive constant} & \text{variable}=\tan\theta & \tan^2\theta+1\text{ becomes }\sec^2\theta \\
& (\text{variable})^2 - \text{positive constant} & \text{variable}=\sec\theta & \sec^2\theta-1\text{ becomes }\tan^2\theta \\
& \text{positive constant} - (\text{variable})^2 & \text{variable}=\sin\theta & 1-\sin^2\theta\text{ becomes }\cos^2\theta \\
\end{array}
$$
In the last one, $\cos\theta$ rather than $\sin\theta$ will also work.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. My mistake in selecting the right words :) thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use the substitution: $\,\,u=\sqrt{\dfrac ab}x$. You 'll have to integrate $ \displaystyle\int \dfrac{\mathrm d\, u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}} $.
Now either you've heard of `inverse` hyperbolic functions and you have the answer.
Either you only know hyperbolic functions; then you can use the substitution: $u=\cosh t,\enspace t\ge 0$. At the end, you'll have to compute the  inverse cosh.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good way to approach these sorts of integration problems.  It won't always lead you directly to a solution, but it often works.  When I write "these sorts," what I mean is:  integrals with **Pythagorean expressions** in them; *i.e.,*  sums or differences of squares inside of a radical (or raised to a power that's an integer multiple of $\frac{1}{2}$).

Notice that $\sqrt{ax^2 - b} = \sqrt{(\sqrt{a}x)^2 - (\sqrt{b})^2}$ is of that form.  Sketch a right triangle with the hypotenuse of length $\sqrt{a}x$ and a leg of length $\sqrt{b}$.  Name the angle between these two sides $\theta$.  Then, the radical expression is the length of the third leg (opposite angle $\theta$).

Write down the trigonometric relationship between $x$ and $\theta$ suggested by your picture.

> $$\cos \theta = \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}x} \qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad \sqrt{b}\sec\theta = \sqrt{a}x$$

From here, you can write down the radical expression in terms of $\tan \theta$ and complete the exercise from there.

Comment: Excellent! I'll keep that in mind :) thank you! a good advice =)

Answer (score 2):

You have some help here  [Integrate: $\int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{(x+a) ^2- b^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412085/integrate-int-fracdxx-sqrtxa-2-b2)
- same case after substitution x=1/y

Comment: You can also see here http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf - formula 32 But it is also sinh or cosh substitution

Comment: You should include the main parts of the link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y= \sqrt{ax^2-b}$. Then,  $dy= \frac{axdx}y$ and

\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2-b}}
&=\int\frac{dx}y
=\int \frac{({a}x+\sqrt a y)\frac{dx}y}{{a}x+\sqrt a y} \\
&= \int\frac{ dy+\sqrt a dx}{\sqrt a(\sqrt{a}x+y)}
=\frac1{\sqrt a}\ln (y+ \sqrt a x)+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

[Euler substitution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) $$\sqrt{ax^2-b}=-\sqrt ax+t$$ gives
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2-b}}=\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt a\; t}=\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{ax^2-b}+ax\right)}{\sqrt{a}}+C$$